# Used EasyBCD to dual boot but grub2 is still loading first

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, easybcd

I have used EasyBCD to make the boot menu be the windows one, but what happens is that my computer boots grub2 first then when i choose windows 7 option, i will be redirected to the easybcd menu.

Comment: That's how it is. There's no point in using EasyBCD. Changes can and should be made at Grub.

Comment: You see Grub first because you boot to Grub.

Comment: update: now that i am not that newbie anymore, what i meant is i liked the display the EasyBCD presents more then the gub2 one + i wanted (not anymore) to boot faster to windows. This can be done if windows was installed after linux, or maybe i make some sort of startup repair in windows, after that i should use EasyBCD.
anw i don't care about windows that much anymore